# How do I connect to serverside DB like SQLite in UIPath?

Tags: sqlite, uipath

I am trying to connect to a SQLiteDB that is on my computer.  But could easily be on my workstation.  I have created a DNS for it in ODBC with a downloaded driver but I'm stuck on how I can connect to this DB in UIPath.

Comment: As far as I understand SQLIte it is NON-server by design and concept. Would you like to elaborate on the "serverside" in your qustion?

Comment: Well, it can sit anywhere.  I guess I should edit it to distinguish from a non-cloud DB.  In my actual example, the SQLite DB is on my desktop computer on my C drive.  My apologies for the confusion

Comment: No need to apologise. I just provided the viewpoint of somebody who got confused. Not even necessarily your mistake... ;-)

Comment: All good my friend.  We are here to help each other.  Thank you for helping me be clearer.  I really love this community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Drag the Database > Connect activity into your sequence or flowchart
- Click on “Configure Settings” and then connection wizard
- Select  for Data Source and “.Net Framework provider for ODBC” for Data Provider
- Click OK
- Select the ODBC DSN name
- If the database requires a user/password, enter that too.
- Then click on test connection, should get a pop up that says "Test Connection succeeded"
  What it will output is a Database Connection.
- While the focus is on the database connection Activity, go to the output section and in the Database Connection, create the variable (Control K) and name the variable.

From here, you can use the connection and other database activities to manipulate it